# ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path in Unity editor

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

When I wanted to build an .apk file of my Unity project with Vuforia SDK, it throws me the following error in the console of Unity:

```
ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:124)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.BuildToolsExe (System.String command)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.get_AAPT ()
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.DumpDiagnostics ()
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer..ctor ()
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:316)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I realized this error is not related with vuforia; instead, it is related to System libraries of C#. but I couldn't understand the log showed above.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your code...

Comment: The error is not related to my code, instead, i think it's related to the main libraries or sdk of c#. I cannot find the /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs to show you the source code